# ExtJS: Linked combobox puzzle

Tags: extjs, combobox

I write special combo object to use it as linked combos. Here it is:

```
comboDivClass = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
            fieldLabel: 'Divisions',
            anchor: '95%',
            lazyRender:true,
            store:new Ext.data.Store({
                  proxy: proxy,
                  baseParams:{rfb_type:'divisions'},
                  reader: divReader,
                  autoLoad: true
            }),
            displayField:'div_name',
            allowBlank:false,
            valueField:'div_id',
            triggerAction:'all',
            mode:'local',
            listeners:{
                select:{
                    fn:function(combo, value) {

                        if (this.idChildCombo) {
                            var modelCmp = Ext.getCmp(this.idChildCombo);
                            modelCmp.setValue('');
                            modelCmp.getStore().reload({
                                params: { 'div_id': this.getValue() }
                            });
                        }   
                    }
                }
            },/**/
            hiddenName:'div_id',
            initComponent: function() {comboDivClass.superclass.initComponent.call(this);}})
```

As you may see, this combobox load data at child combobox store(which set as idChildCombo).
Ok. Here is how i declare it

```
new comboDivClass({id:'sub0div',idChildCombo:'sub1div'}),
new comboDivClass({id:'sub1div'})
```

Yes it works, but it have some odd trouble - it load not only sub1div store, it load at sub0div store too. Why? What im doing wrong?

Comment: `proxy: proxy,`  <--- all instances use one proxy

Comment: no. try it. I tryig to use a different proxy and nothing change. (im trying use different reader too :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see is that you have `mode: 'local'` config, while it should be remote.

Other thing to consider: Why don't you do it more like this:

```
var c1 = new comboDivClass({id:'sub0div'});
var c2 = new comboDivClass({id:'sub1div'});
c1.on('select',function(combo, value) {c2.getStore().reload({
  params: { 'div_id': c1.getValue() }
})});
```

Comment: thanks , but remoting mode: 'local' dont change anything and at your example I get the same result - data loads at both store :(

Answer (score 1):

```
ChildCombo.setMasterField( masterField ) {
  masterField.on('change', function(field){
    this.getStore().filterBy( function(){ //filter by masterFIeld.getValue() } );
  })
}
```

The idea is to link child field to parent not parent to child and this way you can link to any kind form field no only combo.

Here in child combo you have to have store with three columns [group,value,label] where group is value of master field.

This way you can manage to have mode than one master field.